# How to call an object from another class - cannot be accessed

Tags: java

I am trying to call a list of functions from a different class that the one where the list was created. I mean

```
public class FUNCTION {
String fichier=null;    
int nb_link_func=-1;
String fonc_nom=null;
int [] list_id=null;

public FUNCTION() {
    };
};
```

/////////////

```
public class CODE {

FUNCTION [] fonctions;  

public CODE (String tree_file) {
// I fill the variable list_id up, the list of functions
};
}
```

/////////////

```
public class Tree extends JTree {

CODE code=null;
private JTree tree;
String fname=null;

public Tree (String tree_file,DefaultMutableTreeNode top) {
    super(top); 
    code=new CODE(tree_file);

    fname=fonctions[1].getNom(); //This returns cannot find symbol fonctions

    };
};
```

It returns "cannot find symbol fonctions" There is something wrong but I don't find it

Comment: What is wrong?  Are you encountering an error?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make fonctions public by:

```
public FUNCTION [] fonctions;
```

and change:

```
fname=fonctions[1].getNom();
```

to:

```
fname=code.fonctions[1].getNom();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because the constructor of class `Tree` has no visibility of `fonctions[]` array. You need to use an object of class `CODE` which is "code" here. So instead of:

```
fname=fonctions[1].getNom();
```

Try:

```
fname=code.fonctions[1].getNom();
```

Comment: I get  error: fonctions is not public in CODE (filename); cannot be accessed from outside package when adding "code.fonctions...."

Comment: That is because, by default in java, everything in a class can only be accessed inside the same package. So in order to access it change the `fonctions` scope to public,i.e
`public FUNCTION [] fonctions;`